# Restoring entered data after user hits back then forward (ANDROID)

Tags: android

Activity 1 in my application starts Activity 2 when the "next" button is pressed.

If the user hits the back button in Activity 2, the application returns them to Activity 1

If the user then hits the "next" button, the application brings them to Activity 2 again, but anything that was entered in Activity 2 is now blank. Is there any way to keep the data fields in Activity 2 intact?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can save data Using **Shared preferences** it is one of the best mechanism to save and retrieve the data. i.e entered by the user.

SHARED PREFERENCES

you can save data using below mechanism

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
// Store new primitive types in the shared preferences object.
editor.putBoolean("isTrue", true);
editor.putFloat("lastFloat", 1f);
editor.putInt("wholeNumber", 2);
editor.putLong("aNumber", 3l);
editor.putString("textEntryValue", "Not Empty");
// Commit the changes.
editor.commit();
```

later on you can retrieve using below procedure

```
public void loadPreferences() {
// Get the stored preferences
int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, mode);
// Retrieve the saved values.
boolean isTrue = mySharedPreferences.getBoolean("isTrue", false);
float lastFloat = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("lastFloat", 0f);
int wholeNumber = mySharedPreferences.getInt("wholeNumber", 1);
long aNumber = mySharedPreferences.getLong("aNumber", 0);
String stringPreference = mySharedPreferences.getString("textEntryValue", "");
}
```

but the above code should be added in correct activity life cycle methods as per your requirement

i.e may onCreate(), onRestore(), etc

Answer (score 0):

When you go from Activity1(A1) to Activity2(A2) , both are stored in stack with A2 on top .
If you use back button A2 will be popped and you again get the state of A1 . Take care of the same . Avoid back button use .

Store the variables temporarily  combined with the use of OnResume method . It will help you manage thesession state .

Answer (score 0):

If you start an activity using `startactivity` it will create new activity instance always unless you change your `launchMode`,  For not to make Multiple Instances you should  set your activity with launchMode as `singleTask` or `singleTask`,
Refer [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) to select the best the suit for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... If you are only concerned about saving View state on a back button, you can use preferences (say in onStop) as Ramesh states. But there is no reason to save preferences on every call to onStop, only on a hard kill. You can do this by setting a flag isCalledSavedInstanceState to false in onResume, NOT in onCreate. Then set this flag to true in onSavedInstanceState. Then use this flag to write to prefs if !isCalledSavedInstanceState in onStop. The logic here is that onSavedInstanceState is NOT called on a hard kill and IF it is called on a soft kill, it is called before onStop.

EDIT: If the activity has "shared document-like data" then you should be saving state to a database in onPause().

JAL

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your trying to do and your code, you could set your variables as static. Just beware as there are pitfalls to this